# How to aggregate goupby and discard the rows after appearing a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Say I have a given dataframe as below

```
input = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], "values":["l", "m", "c", "l", "l", "l", "l", "c","c", "c"]})
```

and I wanted to remove the extra transactions after "c" appear for an id. say for id 3, the 1st 2 values are "l" and after that all transactions are value c so I only want the 1st c.

```
output = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], "values": ["l", "m", "c", "l", "l", "l", "l", "c"]})
```

I tried to do drop_duplicates on a group by but it is not working as per my expectation:

> input.groupby("id").drop_duplicates("values")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a *boolean mask* where `values` equals `c`, then use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group this mask on `id`, then transform it using `cumsum`, finally use this `mask` to filter the dataframe:

```
# Here 'df' is your 'input' dataframe
mask = df['values'].eq('c').groupby(df['id']).cumsum().gt(1)
df1 = df[~mask]
```

Result:

```
print(df1)

   id values
0   1      l
1   1      m
2   1      c
3   2      l
4   2      l
5   3      l
6   3      l
7   3      c
```

Answer (score 1):

If need remove only `c` rows after first `c` per groups:

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with appended new column with compare `c` for compare values per groups (so tested duplicated by `id` and `c`), chaining by original mask `m` and last filtering by inverse mask by `~`:

```
m = df['values'].eq('c')
df = df[~(df.assign(c = m).duplicated(['id','c']) & m)]
print (df)
   id values
0   1      l
1   1      m
2   1      c
3   2      l
4   2      l
5   3      l
6   3      l
7   3      c
```

Or if need remove all rows after first `c` per groups:

Use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) with boolean mask for remove values after first `c` by filtering with [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) per groups:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 
                   "values":["l", "m", "c", "l", "l", "l", "l", "c","c", "c"]})

df = df[df['values'].eq('c').groupby(df['id']).cumsum().le(1)]
print (df)
   id values
0   1      l
1   1      m
2   1      c
3   2      l
4   2      l
5   3      l
6   3      l
7   3      c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict of the index where the first occurence is by

```
In [24]: first_occurence = input.groupby('id').apply(lambda _df: (_df['values'] == 'c').idxmax() if np.any(_df['values'] == 'c') else None).to_dict()                                                      

In [25]: first_occurence                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[25]: {1: 2.0, 2: nan, 3: 7.0}
```

Here, you need to return `None` if no values are found, otherwise you do leave out the last value if there is no `'c'` for an `id`.

Then you can use `DataFrame.truncate` like this:

```
In [28]: input.groupby('id').apply(lambda _df: _df.truncate(after=first_occurence[_df['id'][0]])).droplevel(0)                                                                                             
Out[28]: 
   id values
0   1      l
1   1      m
2   1      c
3   2      l
4   2      l
5   3      l
6   3      l
7   3      c
```